# Creating a column with mutate based on the sum of a variable from a grepl-based query

Tags: r

I want to take a sum of "play_length" based on "game_id" and "player." Secondarily, I want to include the instances where the "player" value occurs in either the "home_lineup" or "away_lineup" column (it will only occur in one column per game_id) and count them towards the summing of the "play_length". So when a value occurs in the "player" column, I want the new column I create with mutate (called min_played) to be the sum of all play_length values where they occurred in either "home_lineup" or "away_lineup".

Here is a sample of [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R-iv9jGSj9ZUE7dTpp1cWGNPzMw1mIlMoASVxLOJWRo/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to put the values in the yellow-highlighted "min_played" column. The spreadsheet I have linked has enough data to where you will see separate game ID's and players occurring in both columns.

Here is code that I have made that works on a one-at-a-time basis. Ideally, I would want that second line of code to be grouped by "game_id" and then added in a new column.

```
query <- season_data_select %>% filter(grepl("Stephen Curry", home_lineup) | grepl("Stephen Curry", away_lineup))

(sum(query$play_length))/60
```

Comment: How many columns need to be created?

Comment: Just the one "min_played" column. But the value created in that column is based on "play_length" corresponding to the "player" column, which needs to be found in either the "home_lineup" or "away_lineup." The reason why I don't just sum "play_length" by "player" is because I want instances that the value in "player" is in one of the "lineup" columns, not just when they're in the "player" column. So for example, if I want to find "min_played" for Draymond Green in "game_id" 21800002, I'd add the play_length for every time he's in the "home_lineup" and put the value next to him in the new column

Comment: what is the `/60`  is it baesd on the number of rows in query

Comment: The "/60" is because the value that results is in seconds, but I want it as minutes and seconds.

Comment: Can you please add first few output values you expect by editing the post (grouped by 'game_id').  The data you showed is a bigger data.  It is better to provide small example for testing

Comment: @akrun okay, what I did was do that manual-entry code I included above for "Stephen Curry", "Steven Adams", and "Damian Jones". That's what those values will be. I included the full data set just to provide separate "game_id" values.